# Inheritance in Javascript - parent method calls from child methods

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am learning prototype inheritance in Javascript and I tried to write an example which calls a parent method from a child method's prototype. However, I do not get the results which I expected.

**Person.js**

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}


Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
    console.log("Hello, My name is " + this.name + " and I am " + this.age + " years old.")
}

module.exports = Person;
```

**Employee.js**

```
var Person = require('./Person');

var Employee = function(name, age, salary) {
    Person.call(this, name, age);
    this.salary = salary;
}

Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

Employee.prototype.greeting = function() {
    Person.prototype.greeting.call(this);
    console.log("My salary is " + this.salary)
}

module.exports = Employee;
```

**Test.js**

```
var Person = require('./Person');
var Employee = require('./Employee');

var p = new Person("Rob", 24);

p.greeting();

var e = new Employee("Jim", 25, 1200000);

e.greeting();
```

So basically what I have is an `Person` class which has `name` and `age` and a `greeting` method attached to its prototype which print some data. The `Employee` class extends Person and has an additional attribute `salary`. It also overrides the `greeting` method by printing the salary. However, before printing the `salary`, it calls the `super class'` greeting method and then prints the `salary`.

**My expected output was :**

```
Hello, My name is Rob and I am 24 years old.
Hello, My name is Jim and I am 25 years old.
My salary is 1200000
```

**But Actual Output was:**

```
Hello, My name is Rob and I am 24 years old.
Hello, My name is Person and I am 25 years old.
My salary is 1200000
```

I know that the **call()** method needs to be passed arguments along with the context `this`. And it is the name of `this (Person)` that is being replaced as the name which tells that the classes are not purely inherited since I am calling the method inside. I should be able to use `super.methodName()` inside but super does not work here.

***Please tell me if what I have done is how Inheritance in JS is achieved or if I'm doing something wrong.***

***PS:*** I tried to use a super call to greeting like in Java but it gave me an error. Does that mean the Employee class has not extended the Person class ?

Comment: Rename the property `this.name` in `Person`, it conflicts with `Function.name` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person)
```

assigned `Employee.prototype` to a `Person` function.
Functions have a `name` property, that's why it logged the name of that particular function: `Person`.

The `Employee` instance has three pools it can look for properties:

First is Employee instance that has 3 properties:

1. name
2. age
3. salary

Second is Employee prototype (if prop is not found on Employee instance, js looks here) that has 1 method:

1. greeting

Third is Person prototype (if prop is not found on previous objects, js looks here) that has 1 method:

1. greeting

Since `greeting` is both on `Employee.prototype` and `Person.prototype`, you can't access `Person.prototype.greeting` from Employee instance - it will always be blocked by `Employee.prototype.greeting` that is closer in the chain. That's why in:

```
Employee.prototype.greeting = function() {
    Person.prototype.greeting.call(this);
    console.log("My salary is " + this.salary)
}
```

you have to call `Person.prototype.greeting` directly (`this` inside the function is an instance of Employee)

Comment: I've changed `Object.create(Person)` to `Object.create(Person.prototype)`. Is this right or it is always `Object.create(Person)` to enable inheritance ?

Comment: @v1shnu it should be `Object.create(Person.prototype)`. You've changed the code in your answer to the correct one (it returns what you wanted), so i didn't included it in my answer for brevity.

Comment: I want to know why `Person.prototype.greeting.call(this)` is used to call a parent class method. If inheritance is enabled, then should it not be called directly ? Why should I pass `this` again in the call method if I have already set it in the first line of the Employee function.

Comment: @v1shnu If you call `Person.prototype.greeting()` directly, `this` will point to `Person.prototype` not a class instance. If you call `this.greeting()` in `Employee.prototype.greeting` it will call itself again and again.